# Deeper understating of blockchain forks.

Tags: litecoin

Ive spend the last 8 months digesting everything and I have a lot more to learn. Is it possible to use Dogecoin on Litecoin network without converting  through an exchange? I assumed  you could since their both  Scrypt and one is a fork.

Also,  I’d like to go learn more.  I’ve done G code programming for CNC machines but that’s it .  So much info out there,  What would you recommend for learning the basics.
Thanks

Comment: The second question is too vague.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no.

## Forks

A fork can mean that you "forked" the code on a repository, meaning you copied it and modified it for your own use case. It can also mean that the blockchain network itself "forked" when it split the blockchain and the network adopted two different chains and usually code and rules as well.

> Is it possible to use Dogecoin on Litecoin network without converting through an exchange?

Because two different blockchain networks have 2 different blockchains, they have different sources of truth.  One transaction on the forked chain isn't necessarily considered valid on the other (especially if they happened after the fork) because they are reaching consensus on separate blockchains.  See this related question: [Can I do a replay attack to spend my testnet bitcoin on the mainnet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52360/can-i-do-a-replay-attack-to-spend-my-testnet-bitcoin-on-the-mainnet)

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.  Here's why.

First of all let's talk about forks.  Like JBaczuk stated, a fork is simply when you copy the code and alter some information.  So when people say Dogecoin and Litecoin are forked from Bitcoin, they're saying that they have similar code and that some of the parameters have changed.  So even though they are similar, they are different.

Now let's talk about how a blockchain is created.  Miners submit a block in accordance to a set of rules.  An example of a rule is, like you said, the mining algorithm.  Other examples are blocksize limits and blocktimes.  For example, Litecoin's blocktime strives for 2.5 minutes while Dogecoin's is 1 minute.

What happens next is this block gets sent out to the network in order to be "validated."  This means that full nodes that download the whole blockchain choose to accept or reject this block.  Their criteria?  The protocol rules of the network.  So let's say a miner decides to submit a block that has a 1 minute blocktime (Dogecoin) to a 2.5 minute blocktime network (Litecoin).  Even though they share the same mining algo and have similar characteristics, the full nodes in the Litecoin network will reject the 1 minute block and refuse to download it.  Instead, they will wait for a block that fits ALL of the criteria (protocol rules).